# rename filenames recursively to simpler name

Tags: regular-expression, rename

my file names look like:

```
A06_S6_L001_R1_001.fastq
A06_S6_L001_R2_001.fastq
B07_S6_L001_R1_001.fastq
B07_S6_L001_R2_001.fastq
C08_S6_L001_R1_001.fastq
C08_S6_L001_R2_001.fastq
```

and I want:

```
1A06.R1.fastq
1A06.R2.fastq
1B07.R1.fastq
1B07.R2.fastq
etc...
```

in other words, i want to keep the part before the first underscore, the part before the last underscore, put a `.` between them, keep the file extension and put a number in front of the whole thing.
i have the perl rename so i'm guessing it would be best to use this command but i don't know regex...

Comment: is "the number in front" always 1?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because valid solutions have been posted..

Answer (score 1):

**`prename`** approach:

```
prename -n 's/^([^_]+)_.*_([^_]+)_[0-9]+\./1$1.$2./' *.fastq
```

(`-n` - *no action*; show what files would have been renamed)

Answer (score 0):

With bash and `dirname` and an assumption of `1` as the leading prefix:

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in ./**/*.fastq
do
  [[ $file =~ (...)_(..)_(....)_(..)_(...).fastq ]] && 
  printf "%s\n" "mv -- "$file" "$(dirname "$file")"/1${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.${BASH_REMATCH[4]}.fastq"
done
```

And with this sample "input":

```
touch A06_S6_L001_R1_001.fastq A06_S6_L001_R2_001.fastq B07_S6_L001_R1_001.fastq B07_S6_L001_R2_001.fastq C08_S6_L001_R1_001.fastq C08_S6_L001_R2_001.fastq
mkdir subdir
cp *.fastq subdir/
```

This is the resulting output:

```
mv ./A06_S6_L001_R1_001.fastq ./1A06.R1.fastq
mv ./A06_S6_L001_R2_001.fastq ./1A06.R2.fastq
mv ./B07_S6_L001_R1_001.fastq ./1B07.R1.fastq
mv ./B07_S6_L001_R2_001.fastq ./1B07.R2.fastq
mv ./C08_S6_L001_R1_001.fastq ./1C08.R1.fastq
mv ./C08_S6_L001_R2_001.fastq ./1C08.R2.fastq
mv ./subdir/A06_S6_L001_R1_001.fastq ./subdir/1A06.R1.fastq
mv ./subdir/A06_S6_L001_R2_001.fastq ./subdir/1A06.R2.fastq
mv ./subdir/B07_S6_L001_R1_001.fastq ./subdir/1B07.R1.fastq
mv ./subdir/B07_S6_L001_R2_001.fastq ./subdir/1B07.R2.fastq
mv ./subdir/C08_S6_L001_R1_001.fastq ./subdir/1C08.R1.fastq
mv ./subdir/C08_S6_L001_R2_001.fastq ./subdir/1C08.R2.fastq
```

Remove the `printf "%s\n"` if the results look correct.